# How do I make a WordPress theme come with pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a WordPress theme and with it will come a few pages. More specifically, what I want is to put in my `functions.php` the code that will do the same as if I had gone into the Pages section of the GUI and created a new page *Some Page* with permalink `http://mywebsite.com/somepage.php`. I'm not sure how to do this because the WordPress documentation for the its API is not very helpful for looking up how to do this. But from my experience using the WordPress API so far, I'm guessing there's something like

```
add_page('Some Page', 'generate_some_page', 'http://mywebsite.com/somepage.php'); 

function generate_some_page ( ) 
{
    /* 
     echo the HTML that will go inside the <div id="content"> in the layout
        <?php get_header(); ?>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
               <!--  ... -->
            </div>
        </div>
         <?php get_footer(); ?>
    */
}
```

Do you have any idea what WP API call I'm looking for? Or any link to relevant documentation that I can read?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **wp_insert_post**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

```
$page_data = array(
    'post_name'         => 'my-page-name',
    'post_title'        => 'My Page Name',
    'post_content'      => 'This is the content of my page.',
    'post_excerpt'      => 'This is the excerpt of my page.'
);
$page_id = wp_insert_post( $page_data );
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh. A moment ago I was peeking in the `wp_posts` table and saw that pages created with "Add Page" through the GUI are categorized under the `wp_posts` table. So "pages" are a type of "post" in Wordpress land.

Comment: Yes. Post, pages, and media attachments, links, and menu items, are all considered a "Post Type" in WordPress (Can be a little confusing at first but you will pick it up as you learn WordPress more). For the code to add a new page you will just want to include `'post_type' => 'page'` in the **page_data** array to make sure it is added as a page.

Comment: What if I want that page's "content" to have PHP code? Can I somehow make `post_content` draw from a file `some_page_content.php`? Because this page I'm making need to use the database ..